# Is it possible to include images inside nodes of a DOT-language Graph?

Tags: image, graph, dot

I would like to include images (not only text) inside the nodes of a DOT-language graph. Is it possible? I didn't find any example concerning it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Assuming you can use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for your needs)

Reading from [the Graphviz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:image):

> image
>
> Gives the name of a file
>   containing an image to be displayed
>   inside a node. The image file must be
>   in one of the recognized formats,
>   typically JPEG, PNG, GIF or
>   Postscript, and be able to be
>   converted into the desired output
>   format. Unlike with the shapefile
>   attribute, the image is treated as
>   node content rather than the entire
>   node. In particular, an image can be
>   contained in a node of any shape, not
>   just a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I'll just have to get away from the online version which I'm using now. I believe another solution exists with shapes images.